# How to add a query string to a URL using ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using asp.net MVC 3, I would like to **add a query string on every request of Controller's method**, using the following code, the query string is not being added to the URL.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or any other alternative approaches?

```
  public ActionResult Index(string uniquestudentreference)
    {
        return View(eventListVM);
    }
```

---

```
 public class UserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters["uniquestudentreference"] = Various.GetGivenNameUser();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `uniquestudentreference` parameter to have a value in your controller action, you should simply invoke the controller action with the correct url like:

`http://www.someurl.com/<controller>/Index/<uniquestudentreference>`

If you want to affect how you pass information through the url, you should look into customizing your route table (located in `Global.asax`)

You can read more about that here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: What I need is to append a Query String not adding a slug to the URL. This should work as soon as the page load.

Comment: Then i guess you could override the Initialize method of your controller, and add the value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is set the value to the ViewData or TempData of the ControllerContext in the ActionResult, and then reference it in the method. This is a better way to pass it around than querystring, and safer too (avoids user being able to manipulate the value). That or store the value in the Session.